# Networkx: List of leaf nodes in Barabasi Albert Graph

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

How is it possible to get the list of all leaf nodes in Barabasi Albert Graph.

```
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use a list comprehension.

```
g = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10, 2)
leaf_nodes = [node for node in g if nx.degree(node)==1]
```

Note that in networkx `node in g` works just like `node in g.nodes()`.

Comment: It is indeed more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

## Finding leaf nodes

Leaf nodes have one degree:

```
g = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10, 2)
leaf_nodes = []
for node in g.nodes():
    if nx.degree(g,node) == 1:
        leaf_nodes.append(node)

print(leaf_nodes)
```